# json files saved with trailing "?"

Tags: ruby, json

I'm saving a bunch of data as a hash and saving it as a json file. Code for the saving:

```
    def write_to_file(id, data)
       Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__)+"/specs")
       filename = "./"+id+".json"
       File.open("#{filename}", 'w') do |f2|  
          f2.write(data.to_json)
       end 
    end
```

I want to save it as id.json, but the file is getting saved with a "?" at the end. For example, 199015806906670?.json where the original value of "id" is 199015806806670.
If I search for 19901580606670 I am also unable to use TAB to autocomplete. 
Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT:
Sample from file containing the ids:

104184946332304
131321736945390
693134284084652
146974018804301
288608807960773

Code to get these:

```
    url = File.open("newapps/curlist.txt","r")
    url.each_line do |line|
      func1(line) #func1 calls write_to_file, no changes to line in func1
    end
```

Comment: Sounds like something else in your code must be modifying `id` and appending a `?` before you call `write_to_file`

Comment: @mikej I just checked, when I print id alone it prints 
305920579527310 but when I print filename this is what I see on screen:
./305920579527310
.json

There's some sort of gap between the 0 in ./30592057927310 and the .json part. Is there some way for me to save the filename as *.json without this? Or to open the file in spite of this?

Comment: Sounds like some extra character on the end of the id that prints as a a space character when you try to print the filename but prints as a ? when viewing in the Terminal/command line. In Ruby try doing `puts "'#{filename}'"` i.e. outputting `filename` surrounded by single quotes. You should see a space inside the single quotes, confirming the extra character is part of the `id`. Where does `id` come from?

Comment: I tried what you said and get the same response, sorry: It should have said 
./305920579527310  
.json   
 in my previous message too.
That's not a space, it should be a newline between the number and .json but I can't seem to print them on separate lines

Comment: @mikej: This is what appears
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ebd0dcb8fbeac208c83f

Comment: Ok, you haven't mentioned where `id` comes from.. does it come from user input. In any case you can strip a new line from the end using `chomp` e.g. `filename = id.chomp + ".json"`

Comment: @mikej: I open a file and the ids are stored on each line. Ah, I see the problem. I think since I'm reading from a file, there's an automatic trailing newline. Ok, if I'm matching now, I'll need to append a newline to my regex ie. From 12345, I need 12345\n.json . How can I do this?

Comment: I need to finish up in a ad but if you update your question to include an example of what the file storing the ids looks like and the code you're using to read this file and extract the ids using regexps I'm sure someone can help. If not I can take a look tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80489/discussion-between-tvishwa107-and-mikej).

Comment: Just `chomp` the ID.

Comment: @DaveNewton as a follow up, how can I insert this character back in the filename? There's a lot of data, so if it were possible to find a workaround to re-assimilate it that would be perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments you likely have a newline as the last character of your `id` field.  The character (being invalid) is being replaced with a question mark.

Use this to remove the newline...

```
filename = "./"+id.chomp+".json"
```